# Find all invariant subspaces of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find all invariant subspaces of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

This question has many posts online. The problem is that i also need to show that there are no more  subspaces. The best I've got so far is to determine the eigenvectors $v=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$. So thus we find $Sp\{0\}$, $Sp\{v\}$ are subspaces. But $Sp(v, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix})$ also seems to be a invariant subspace, despite the fact that $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is no eigenvector. Is there a general algorithm to find all invaiant subspaces? I also tried a more algebraic approach. One can show that $Sp(v_1,v_2)$ invariant subspace iff $T(v_1) \in V$ and $T(v_2) \in V$ but this gets really complicated...

Comment: Assuming you're working on $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ , there are not many options for non trivial invariant subspaces, are there? Any such thing will be of the form $\;Span\left\{\;\binom ab\;\right\}\;$ , with not both $\;a,b=0\;$ ...

Comment: I think what I see my thinking problem. Sp(v, (0,1))=R thus we don't need to worry about this.

Comment: Indeed so. That's a trivial inv. space.

Answer (score 1):

The comments will have now shown you that there are exactly three invariant subspaces: $0$, $\text{span} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Is there an algorithm for determining every invariant subspace of a given matrix? Yes. That has to do with the Jordan normal form of the matrix.